# create ear in grails

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails, ear

grails supports creation of war. But is there any command to create an ear through grails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no direct support in Grails,  but this Gant script will do the job. Simply added to `scripts/` dir and invoked as `grails ear`.

Script originally posted by [Graeme on mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Gant-Grails-EAR-td1588511.html#a1588684)

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsWar")

target(ear: "Creates an EAR file from a Grails WAR") {
    war()   
    event("StatusUpdate", ["Building EAR file"])
    generateApplicationXml()
    def warDest = new File(warName).parentFile
    def earFile = "${projectTargetDir}/${contextRoot}.ear"
    ant.ear(destfile:earFile, appxml:appXml, update:true) {
        fileset(dir:warDest, includes:"*.war")
    }
    event("StatusFinal", ["Done creating EAR $earFile"])
}
target(defineContextRoot:"defines the context root") {
    contextRoot = "${grailsAppName}${grailsAppVersion ? '-'+grailsAppVersion : ''}" 
}
target(generateApplicationXml:"Generates an application.xml file") {
    depends(defineContextRoot)
    def warDest = new File(warName)
    appXml = "${projectTargetDir}/application.xml"
    new File(appXml).write """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<application 
xmlns=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/ 2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http:// java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ application_1_4.xsd" 
       version="1.4"> 
<display-name>${grailsAppName}</display-name> 

<module> 
    <web> 
        <web-uri>${warDest.name}</web-uri> 
        <context-root>${contextRoot}</context-root> 
    </web> 
 </module> 

</application>  
"""
}

setDefaultTarget(ear)
```

Comment: Any reason why this is not part of the grails framework?

Comment: Maybe this script worked for earlier versions of grails, but for `2.3.4` I got an error stating that the warName property does not exist. Solved it by defining it within the script as `warName = "${basedir}/target/${grailsAppName}-${grailsAppVersion}.war"`. I checked from the sources and it seems that the warName property is present in WarCreator.groovy (and maybe also in _GrailsWar script), but not visible to Ear script for some reason.

Comment: but grails ear generate for development environment, i need create for production environment

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer, but nowadays the grails maven plugin is pretty good. So you could just build an ear out of the war produced by the grails maven plugin.