# How to generate EAR file in GRAILS 3?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails3

I want to generate ear file using GRAILS 3. I tired using Gradle ear plugin did not work? how do I do it please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a groovy script to make a ear in grails 3 I hope this helps you.

[create ear in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872954/create-ear-in-grails)

and run grails ear command.

Comment: This may work for earlier versions, not for grails 3.